# Is tofu cheese "kitniyot" on Passover?

Tags: halacha, passover, ashkenazi, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

I know Ashkenazi Jews don't eat "kitniyot", certain beans and the like, on Pessach.

Is tofu cheese included in that restriction? It's made primarily of soybeans.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Can you [edit] your question to make it less personal? We [try to avoid practical halachic questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. We hope to see you around!

Comment: I've edited this per @Scimonster's comment. Please consult your rabbi about your specific case.

Comment: For clarification - some people call the block of tofu itself, "cheese", esp. when it' sthe hard tofu. I assume you are talking about something like the "Tofutti" cream cheese and similar, correct? For that matter, you could extend your question to tofu ice cream, soy protein, and such. They would be in the same category - all tofu bi-products. AAOF, tofu, itself, is a bi-product of soy beans. Your question (answer) would apply to soy sauce, as well.

Answer (score 4):

There is no definitive answer. [See](http://ph.yhb.org.il/en/04-09-06/) [some](http://www.ybm.org.il/hebrew/LessonArticle.aspx?item=3062) [links](http://www.srugim.co.il/30698-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%93%D7%91-%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%92%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A8-%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9C-%D7%91%D7%95%D7%98?di=1) [permitting](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?id=18466) and [some](http://www.kashrut.com/Passover/kitniot_list/) [links](http://koshernexus.org/holidays/passover/our-position-on-kitniyot-derivatives/) [forbidding](http://www.aish.com/h/pes/l/48964186.html) and [some](http://vbm-torah.org/archive/moadim70/05-70moed.htm) [links](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/871998/jewish/Know-Thy-Beans.htm) [equivocating](http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/264938-%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97-%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%99%D7%94). It's hard to say either side should be viewed as violating halacha.

Speak to your rabbi for a ruling and be sure that the product is certified for Pesach regarding the other ingredients.

Comment: You are right about Link 1, I didn't notice that before. Regarding link 3, I don't think the following is a clear indication that R' Lior considers soybeans definitively non-*kitnoyos* (by, "therefore... the prohibition of kitniyos doesn't apply to them," I think he just means according to those poskim): "לפי הרבה מהפוסקים האחרונים, סויה אינה בכלל קטניות... אי-לכך, מה שלא היה בכלל הגזירה בזמנם, לא חל עליו איסור קטניות בזמננו. בנוסף, גם לפוסקים המחמירים בסויה לאוסרו מדין קטניות, כל זמן שהקטניות לא באו במגע עם מים, מותר לאכלם"...

Comment: ... And though Link 1 claims R' Lior agrees with him that soybeans are definitively not *kitniyos*, the footnote he uses to support this only says that R' Lior gave R' Yehuda's essay generic praise. Either way, it's clear that there are those who permit soy as non-kitniyos, and those who don't.

Comment: Nice edit, +1, though I'm still uncertain about R' Lior.

Answer (score 3):

Tofu is made from soybeans which [are kitniot](http://www.kashrut.com/Passover/Kitniyot/), so yes, tofu cheese would be included in the prohibition of kitniot.

Comment: This answer presents only one side of an active Machloket.